# Dataframe with different number of rows

Tags: r, row

There are 5 columns. Columns 1,2,3, and 5 have 252 data points.  Column 4 has 58 data points.

This is my code:

```
    Dpercent <- data.frame(percentAAport, percentIBMport, percentFBport, 
                           percentTWTRport, percentMSFTport) 
    #the percentXXport are the col. variable names
```

I browsed through similar questions and tried several answers users gave, such as:

```
as.data.frame
cbindX
rbindX
cbindPad
rbindPad
```

But they all failed (unless I messed up - I am a newbie).
My ideas for solutions:

Adding rows 0:194 with data of "0" or "NA" to column 4, but I do not know how to do that.

Or running a loop for column 4, attributing a "0" or "NA" to each of the first 194 rows.

Other Information:

I will eventually use matrix multiplication on the data frame and would like to use built-in functions like `sort` on the data frame.
The column data is inputed from an online source and has undergone some mathematical computation in R already.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dpercent <- data.frame(percentAAport, percentIBMport, percentFBport, 
                       percentTWTRport= c( rep(NA, 194), percentTWTRport),
                       percentMSFTport)
```